# What is a Shimura variety?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms

It so look like that Shimura variety is a modular space that contains classes of zeros of modular functions that have certain symmetry that have structure of Hodge type.
Is this true?

Comment: https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf

Comment: In my opinion, to have a reasonable answer, this question needs to include more information about what you already know about Shimura varieties: What examples are you familiar with? Do you understand the pieces of the definition on a formal level and are looking for intuition about how they fit together, or is there some part of the definition you already don't understand? It would also be helpful to expand on terms in your question like "modular space", "contains classes of zeroes", "have certain symmetry".

Comment: I understood the definition of modular functions well,I also understood the idea of classes of varieties as quotient spaces,I understood the idea of a Hodge structure but I don't see clearly the intuition of Shimura variety as it fit into all these ideas...

Comment: Do you understand Hilbert modular surfaces and moduli spaces of principally polarized abelian varieties?

Comment: Know some Hilbert modular surface but not polarized abellian variety

Comment: [Shimura variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimura_variety).

Comment: As well as Milne's lecture notes, you could also try this two-page overview article in the AMS Notices, https://www.ams.org/notices/201211/rtx121101560p.pdf, whose title is precisely "What is ... a Shimura variety?"

Comment: @DavidLoeffler.thank you it clear some confusion